# Can every inscribable 3-polytope be circumscribed while still preserving the maximum symmetry of its canonical form?

Tags: graph-theory, symmetry, spheres, polyhedra

According to Steinitz's theorem, it is possible to prove that every 3-connected graph G(P) represents the skeleton of a convex 3-polytope P, which can be realized in R3 from its skeleton G(P). Various approaches, such as [Hart's algorithm](https://www.georgehart.com/virtual-polyhedra/canonical.html) and the [circle packing theorem](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271536/1-s2.0-S0012365X00X02518/1-s2.0-0012365X9390340Y/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEGAaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIAYOkFjtVcJd4B1Qu2vLAG6WIVI6d98KC7pS7g6t5D9BAiBVKHmozocA8AsRbrc2ziApFRlaTrstNFPCajG0aX9gyiq8BQjZ%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAUaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIM5AeEOoMytCEZL76ZKpAFnvcXuj6k5poS%2FeiW7EiIhSnGBvmZgGUwTeLzL9YM8K%2F%2F%2BDbVuYl6xwIbkrJ39a6SRBsnAuUu0fkif9tMEwdEb%2FhgA0dmiSvWGu76ECaqqDf97p7lu7masgbB8Wl4hJEGAihc67lfNum0s7oONORTNqf8J06ZQ%2F%2F5LfUQbY9PHuMUVy23gM5Hh31NFBxax9ZH0HKD%2FOmrP16HkCAkf7yWVdNlfbo%2F8n53Vo7FB12BKU8HMMWIFWttzWipCDHIi2tyZwx5%2BMBf5vhBPiSXP9zpviEm9J2eZNMrS6uowGnO1t7kv4vlPZpbPqUCPtIxCLdUA2VhNOgcZqvszEDrVyaMezcq8uV41j0KcJPK4TChdgUzM%2BS1kWKdU5lzafyhZkU9srPcRd%2FVKhflNLIqQpvVrloFUaXUhZZq%2FRV5RqPxq087%2BGcpDCRMpl1kAK%2FoCZA2UrUD2PbZmAFF8KoyBMm927B%2Bvp%2FBTZ4oLcFd8K6wOHWPwKUaYDNqIv3SExU6PDgtYszxg8EOnEl83qyWBmM5pSyvW4SoxPUzEbuisrh5kKDOT1FwuQut8dT8acj%2BghazX0gGZbSikQA35G5jqolYhnsE85p3ZlfkzeguuQe6rsf63qm3JyzqpMcAUaYQXaOJK7nOglrKBWu22Re4lnWuWUjp%2Bw4PJWqm9DqL%2BaL1EJT%2Fnit%2FLmdxqZ%2Bhim4ZSdTd1Fg1JaZyan3U4k2ZJLbPaKriIifougq0DFl4xoARIhu7VkYpDBLUzRVwWnF%2FlbeKJTJD8LYPtdE5OwHXS1o75AmT9h%2FQhLoTGVDKKqibT%2FgyFmxcbgGlQxA5Ix1Z9mwnLZzNDiQCBWJ4iaZ6bMPDOO2FqoOk3%2BtxoRj4NDFZf0Ew4Ze7pQY6sgGnD7GkiDzQNRXqafaOK%2BstEg2twPvLiAZmR66hQ1D%2FFZpGyBIdqC5Mst3Enmr8OlsUWOleVarYIo6vJb39ae3Y%2BUauQwClrc97kPbp0zuGf0ph6KbeLt1XOVZ5O%2FID%2FbvO3n3brhDtExlY0N5WDqmEJgTgk71gb4N3p95A0q8i6%2B%2BpUHGHO8EpKUj1%2Bjk2pCIotyBcOBJvieSkbpMDGZXUnBUn8l8gfdkSlyH9Csrp5RmI&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230712T165806Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYQZH3A456%2F20230712%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=43f2f05a7e98abb4d1505c0320231a38fbb12f45eb778aedcf3a36f9a427fddf&hash=2a493e4bfa1c32647db4943aea283735d94c8877dbd4d05843de2a9949f51f8a&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0012365X9390340Y&tid=spdf-32b7870d-050a-4db4-b832-95ca71b135fa&sid=fdd656a179ccc544da89bcc-130c43e0eee4gxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=04105101500f05505403&rr=7e5ad43a58f900c9&cc=br), can be used to achieve this and obtain the [canonical form of P](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265707162_Algorithms_for_drawing_polyhedra_from_3-connected_planar_graphs), which is a polyhedral representation with the highest possible symmetry. In this form, all the edges of P touch a unit sphere. However, instead of an edge-tangent form, it might be desirable to have a circumscribed representation of P where the vertices touch a unit sphere instead of the edges. While not all 3-polytopes are inscribable (e.g., [Triakis tetrahedron](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669817300136)), can we ensure that for those with inscribability properties, there exists an optimal circumscribed form that preserves the symmetry of the canonical one?